# Is it safe to use pointers as map keys in Go?

Tags: memory, data-structures, go, garbage-collection

Suppose we add a value to a map using a pointer as the key. Could the memory address of this pointer ever change? If so, will looking it up in the map fail because when it was inserted, it had a different memory address?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Could the memory address change, in the pointers-as-uints sense? Yes, but outside of [the unsafe package](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) go doesn't expose pointers as uints. So, will looking it up in the map fail? No.

See more at [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types). The linked section even includes a pointer-keyed map as an example.

Comment: Same idea from another angle: the spec's promised to keep pointer-keyed maps working if any future implementation has a moving GC.

Comment: @twotwotwo Where? I can't see that promise in the spec

Comment: Yeah, that's a fair criticism of my phrasing. The idea is that if things like pointer comparisons or pointer-keyed maps are valid according to the spec, the usual ideas of how equality and maps work should continue to apply as the implementation changes--pointers that were equal shouldn't start comparing unequal due to GC, and a key that once found an entry in a map shouldn't suddenly fail to due to GC. But I'm not saying there's a specific, explicit sentence in the spec about pointer-keyed maps working in a hypothetical Go implementation with a moving GC.

Comment: Also this [mailing list discussion](https://golang-nuts.narkive.com/dmTQZxhx/go-nuts-is-it-safe-to-use-pointer-as-map-key) confirms this.